# can't load android virtual device

Tags: android

when i want to use AVD there is an error:

```
[Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define    
Lcom/willis/layout/Client_layoutActivity$1;
[client_layout] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/willis/layout/Client_layoutActivity$1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had these messages:

```
[2013-01-22 21:36:43 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2013-01-22 21:36:43 - Prueba1] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl
```

What I did was, in Eclipse, go to my **Android Dependencies** directory, then right click on it, select **Build Path** then **Remove from Build Path**, *Clean* your project and *Build*. Maybe you want to uncheck *Build Automatically* option.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I lost my project doing so

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related with the AVD in any way but to the process of dexing (convert into Dalvik Executable), which are then zipped into a single .apk file on the device.

It seems that you are including `com.willis.layout.Client_layoutActivity$1` more than once.

Answer (score 0):

This is a build path issue. Make sure your bin folder is not included in your build path. Right click on your project, go to properties and then Build Path. Make sure that Honeycomb library is in your libs/ folder and not in your source folder. Include the libraries in libs/ individually in the build path. BTW, you may want to bring in the android-support-v4 library to get Ice Cream Sandwich support instead of the Honeycomb support library.